# How to manage an inaccessible remote windows server

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, firewall

I have a Windows server that hosts my applications. The server in question is managed by a third party company.  This server is accessible by remote desktop from a jump box.

**During the configuration of my server I activated  domain firewall which has for effect, to prevent the connections via RDP.**

I made an incident ticket with the people who manage the virtual machines but the person who takes care of it is currently unavailable. I absolutely must access the server.

I tried sc command :

```
sc \\RemoteServerName getkeyname "Windows FireWall"
sc \\RemoteServerName stop mpsvc (name of firewall service)
```

But I can no longer connect via sc command.

Is there a way to configure the remote server to access the connection again via RDP, or disable the firewall?

Answer (score 1):

If this machine is a standalone server and not part of a domain, your options are limited.

1. If you have access to [out of band management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-band_management) you can use that to log into the server and change the firewall rules.
2. If the server is part of a domain and you're able to create Group Policies, you can create an OU for the server and create a policy that enables RDP in the firewall.  (Computer Configuration -> Policies -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security -> Inbound Rules;  Under Programs and Services click the Settings button for "Specify the services to which this rule applies" and choose Remote Desktop Services.)
3. If the machine isn't part of a domain and you can copy files to it, you can create the group policy in step 2 on a test machine and copy the resulting files from  %systemroot%\system32\grouppolicy\ on the test machine to  %systemroot%\system32\grouppolicy\ on the server.  You'll then need to force a reboot somehow (or wait for gpupdate to run, usually ninety minutes to two hours).

1 and 2 are your best options.  3 may or may not work, or may break other things on the server if you've set local security policies.